# MySQL test if function is available

Tags: mysql, functions, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Since MySQL 5.8 the function `GeomFromText()` is no longer available and one should use `ST_GeomFromText()` instead, which works exactly the same. Progress, of course :-(

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_geomfromtext

Now I'd like to use this function in a way that is backwards compatible so it can run on very old MySQL server versions as much as possible. What is the best way to check if this function is defined and which of the two (if any) I can use? I'd like to prevent having to check the version number of the server to select the correct query, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, [VERSION()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_version) function and Dynamic SQL:

```
SET @dynamic_func_name = CONCAT(IF(LEFT(VERSION(),3)>'5.6','ST_',''),'GeomFromText');
SET @sql = CONCAT('CALL ',@dynamic_func_name,'(wkt,srid)');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

I used the left 3 character of the [VERSION()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_version) to get the major release. Why ?

- If `LEFT(VERSION(),3)` returns `5.7` or more, `@dynamic_func_name` will be `ST_GeomFromText`
- If `LEFT(VERSION(),3)` returns `5.6` or less, `@dynamic_func_name` will be `GeomFromText`

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I was looking for a way to do this without checking version numbers. That feels like 'user agent sniffing', which is frowned upon in the web dev world, for good reason.

Comment: @MichielB that's only because in the web world you're accommodating more than one client for your code. In this case, you're only accommodating MySQL. It's not like Trident is declaring itself "Mozilla."

Comment: Well, with MariaDB on the scene, there *are* actually more clients for the code!